# Code to run after .each loop is completed

Tags: jquery

I have tried many different ways to do this.
Like in below code I have tried to run a code after the `.each` iteration is completed.

```
  function test(){
    var iterate = $.each(ohrArray, function(i, val){

      var ohrID = ohrArray[i];
      var folderUrl = 'EFMSEmployeeDocumentList' + "/" + locationFolder;
      var url = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + folderUrl + "')?$expand=Files";

      $.getJSON(url,function(data,status,xhr){

        for(var i = 0; i < data.Files.length;i++){
          modifiedDate= new Date(data.Files[i].TimeLastModified);
          if(documentTitle == ""){
            showData(ohrID ,data.Files[i].Title,data.Files[i].ServerRelativeUrl,modifiedDate);
            countItems++;
          }else{
            if(documentTitle == data.Files[i].Title)

              countItems++;
              showData(ohrID ,data.Files[i].Title,data.Files[i].ServerRelativeUrl,modifiedDate);
          }
        }
      }
    }).complete(function(){

      $('#tblCustomListData').dataTable({
        paging: true,
        searching: true,
        bDestroy: true,
        "iDisplayLength": 5,
        "lengthMenu": [5,10, 25, 50, 100]
      });
      if(countItems == 0){
        alert("No Files Exists");
        $("#divCustomListData").hide();
      }
    });
  }
});


  $.when(iterate)
  .then(function(iterate){
    if(countItems == 0){
      alert("No Files Exists");
    }
  });
}
```

Still while debugging I see that the code of `.then` is running before the .each has completed.

What else can we do?

Answer (score 2):

`iterate` should be a Promise.

When you pass in `$.when()` something that's not a Promise it defaults to an already resolved one so the `$.then()` is executed immediately.

To use Promises in jQuery check [$.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)

Then again, you're checking `countItems` which gets updated only when each ajax call responds. So what you really need is to ditch `.complete()` altogether and have an *array* of Promises. Each iteration in `.each` will create a new Promise in the array and then we'll use `$.when()` to check when **all** the Promises are resolved.

```
function test(){
    var promises = []; //

    $.each(ohrArray, function(i, val){
      var d = $.Deferred(); // keep the reference to the promise
      promises.push(d); // push the promise into the array

      var ohrID = ohrArray[i];
      var folderUrl = 'EFMSEmployeeDocumentList' + "/" + locationFolder;
      var url = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + folderUrl + "')?$expand=Files";

      $.getJSON(url,function(data,status,xhr){

        for(var i = 0; i < data.Files.length;i++){
          modifiedDate= new Date(data.Files[i].TimeLastModified);
          if(documentTitle == ""){
            showData(ohrID ,data.Files[i].Title,data.Files[i].ServerRelativeUrl,modifiedDate);
            countItems++;
          }else{
            if(documentTitle == data.Files[i].Title)

              countItems++;
              showData(ohrID ,data.Files[i].Title,data.Files[i].ServerRelativeUrl,modifiedDate);
          }
        } // end of for loop
        d.resolve(); // the ajax in this iteration has been resolved
      }
    });

    // $.when doesn't accept array of promises by default
    $.when.apply(this, promises).then(function(){
      // now all the promises have been resolved

      // code inside the .complete you had in your question
      $('#tblCustomListData').dataTable({
        paging: true,
        searching: true,
        bDestroy: true,
        "iDisplayLength": 5,
        "lengthMenu": [5,10, 25, 50, 100]
      });
      if(countItems == 0){
        alert("No Files Exists");
        $("#divCustomListData").hide();
      }

      iterate.resolve();
    });
  }
});


}
```

I may have misformatted or misplaced some brackets because i didn't run the code.

Comment: why are you writing ` iterate.resolve();` in complete function of ajax call. The code execution may not  reach there in few cases. can it not be done just before the completion of .each loop

Comment: My fault, I thought you wanted the code to run on ajax completion. I'll edit my answer but before that, let me ask for clarification: do you want the code to run after all the iterations in `.each` have completed or just after the `.each()` statement. I'm asking because the functions inside `.each` are called asynchronously and the statement after `.each()` is called immediately, way before the iterations are finished.

Comment: @KumarV ok you know what. What does `.complete()` even do? I couldn't find it in jQuery's docs. Even if I suppose that it's an alias for a ajaxComplete event listener (i.e it sets a handler when an ajax request is complete) then it would just be fired off once. But you've got a bunch of requests. Anyway, since you're checking `countItems` which get's updated only inside an ajax success, I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: it throws me error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`

Comment: how about now? (I changed `$.prototype.when` to `$.when`  - sorry lack of morning coffee)

Comment: Thanks vassi but while debugging I still see that the code inside `$.when` runs before the code inside `$.getJSON`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution from dataTable [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/objects.txt",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Otherwise I think you should change your API so you can give the API a list of `folderURL`s.
Then you don't need to send a request in every loop of your `.each()`.
Further you should be able to create the `dataTable` in the `success` callback of one and only `getJSON`

Comment: How would I pass a list of folderURL

Answer (score 0):

You are make XMLHTTPRequeat inside the `$.each` so I suppose you want to execute some code when all the requests are processed. This won't happen directly as JS is async in nature.

You can keep some counter variable to keep track of the total requests processed. Something like this:

```js
var iterate = $.each(ohrArray, function(i, val) {

      var url = "......";
      var counter = 0;
      $.getJSON(url, function(data, status, xhr) {

        counter++;
        /**** Rest of the code ****/

        if (counter == ohrArray.length) {
          // Execute the required code by pasting it here or calling a function.
        }

      });

    }
```

Comment: here is one more problem because the second `getJSON` request could send an answer faster than the first `getJSON` request. I think if you want to do this by this way, you have to make a synchronous ajax call which in not nice

Comment: No this will work fine as I am incrementing the counter variable and it will equate to the length of `ohrArray` only when all the requests are returned successfully..

Comment: Sorry I've got an overflow in my head. You are right - this will work

Comment: I don't like the case to send a lot of requests (which will take longer too) if you can handle this only by one request. But if it will help, so the author can upvote your answer

Comment: But I have the condition that locationFolder in not null, if its null it wont reach the code where you increment counter